# POST in Javascript for GroupMe API (POST)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, post

I'm trying to make a client for GroupMe using the API that it provides but I'm unable to figure out what's wrong with what I'm doing.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"message": { "text": "Nitin is holding me hostage", "source_guid": "7374"}}' https://api.groupme.com/v3/groups/30885833/messages?token=I_PUT_MY_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE
```

I've done that command and it successfully returns:

[Click here to see JSON (Hastebin)](https://hastebin.com/oqojunigij.json)

My issue is putting this into Javascript code where I've done that like so:

```js
var HTTPS = require('https');
var request = require('request');

function postMessage() {
    var options, body, botReq;  

    options = {
        hostname: 'api.groupme.com',
        path: '/v3/groups/30885833/messages?token=DbZoE9Eablg43ZIGdfKsFkXDjLzR6RDUkwHT9JNn',
        method: 'POST'
    };

    body =
        { '"message"': { '"text"': "I am a post message", '"source_guid"': "7374" } };  

    console.log(body); 

    botReq = HTTPS.request(options, function (res) {
        if (res.statusCode == 201) {
            //neat
        } else {
            console.log('rejecting a bad status code ' + res.statusCode);
        }
    });

    botReq.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log('error posting message ' + JSON.stringify(err));
    });
    botReq.on('timeout', function (err) {
        console.log('timeout posting message ' + JSON.stringify(err));
    });
    botReq.end(JSON.stringify(body));
}
```

But this returns, and only returns Error Code of 400 and I'm not sure how to find the other information relating to why it is a `Bad Request`.

Essentially, I'm asking how do I transform the command that I gave above to javascript, properly. Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked whether there is information inside the response body ...?

Comment: @CBroe I don't know how to, usually I'd just throw off the . statusCode of res.statusCode but `console.log(res);` reports [Object object]

Comment: That's because you're forcing conversion to a string value by using the `+` operator in console.log ...

Comment: Ah! Let me fix that and get back to you.

Comment: @CBroe It threw me a giant prompt but didn't give me an error as to what happened and why I am getting a 400 error code. So, is my JS code wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "a giant prompt"? Anyway, instead of logging stuff from within the script code, you might as well just inspect the request in network panel.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is how you are defining body like this

> body =
>           { '"message"': { '"text"': "I am a post message", '"source_guid"': "7374" } };

You end up with an object that literally has the key "message", instead of message.

Try:

> body = {"message": { "text": "Nitin is holding me hostage", "source_guid": "7374"}}

Comment: No, that changed nothing.  Still receiving a 400 Bad Request.